# Pandas, count grouped values (i.e. count with multiplicity)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of the form:

```
r= pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'value': [4.0, 5.5, 6.0, 4.0, 5],
    'label': ["A", "A", "B", "B", "A"],
})
```

note that each `id` can be repeated, and the same `label` can be applied to different `id`s. 
I want to count how many different labels I have, but not double counting the ones that have the same id. So in this case the output would be

```
>>> r.something()
{"A": 2, "B": 1}
```

This is what I came out with, but it seems to be there is an easier way I am not seeing.

```
rr = r.groupby('id').agg({"label": lambda x: x.values[0]}).reset_index()
```

this produces a `DataFrame` of the type

```
    id  label   value
0   1   A       4.0
1   1   A       5.5
```

then I can do the usual counting

```
rr.groupby('label').size()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will produce what you need

```
r.drop_duplicates(['id','label']).label.value_counts()
Out[118]: 
A    2
B    1
Name: label, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` and `nunique`?

```
r.groupby('label')['id'].nunique()

#label
#A    2
#B    1
#Name: id, dtype: int64
```